# Javascript is not working with my _form.html.erb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm doing fixed deposit project using ruby on rails. In that _form if i select some values from periods it should automatically display the text box value for rate_of_interest. I have tried some javascript but it doesn't work. Here is my code.

> **_form.html.erb**

**inside script tag<>**

```
var roivalues = {

    '12 Months': 9.5,
    '24 Months': 10,
    '36 Months': 10.5,
    '48 Months': 11,
    '60 Months': 11.5
};


var form = document.getElementById('roidetails');

form.elements.noy.onchange = function ()

 {
    var form = this.form;

    form.elements.roi.value = roivalues[this.value];

};





<%= form_for @fd, :html => {:id => "roidetails"} do |f| %>  

<% if @fd.errors.any? %>


<h4>Couldn't open FD Account</h4>

<ul>

<% @fd.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>

<li><%= error %></li>

<% end %>

</ul>


<% end %>


    <%= f.label :Period %>

    <%= f.select :noy, options_for_select(%w[12months 24months 36months 48months 60months]), { :include_blank => true}, :onchange => 'setroi(document.Form, this.value);' %>


    <%= f.label :Rate_of_interest %><span class="help-block">auto-generated</span>

    <%= f.text_field :roi, :id => 'roi', :disabled => true %>

  </div>

    <%= f.submit "Open FD", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  

    <% end %>

  </div>

</div>
```

I don't know why javascript is not working.

Kindly give some ideas to get me out.

Thanks...

Comment: What exactly not working, are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: please post more description about the setroi js function.

Comment: @Sandeeproop: When i select 12months(select :noy) i want to get the rate of interest 9.5% in textbox(text_field :roi) automatically. For that alone am trying the above javascript.

Comment: @Sanket: i have followed this site for my task  http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?829210-Setting-the-Value-of-a-text-box-based-on-the-value-of-a-Select-Box

Comment: Hey @yogi that sitepoint.com js is working on the select tag name, please check your form's select tag name and it replace with form.elements.<select field name>.onchange = function ()

Comment: @Sanket: My select field name is noy so i am using <script>
var roivalues = {
    '12 Months': 9.5,
    '24 Months': 10,
    '36 Months': 10.5,
    '48 Months': 11,
    '60 Months': 11.5
};
var form = document.getElementById('roidetails');
form.elements.noy.onchange = function () {
    var form = this.form;
    form.elements.roi.value = roivalues[this.value];
};
</script>    But, its not working

Comment: @Sanket: on that sitepoint they use province as select field name and for me noy(f.select :noy) is the select field name but, its not working, help me boss...

Comment: :) ok Please give me your form html code from browser....

Comment: Can you please provide HTML output of <%= f.select :noy, options_for_select(%w[12months 24months 36months 48months 60months]), { :include_blank => true}, :onchange => 'setroi(document.Form, this.value);' %>

Comment: @Sanket  <label for="fd_Period">Period</label>
    <select id="fd_noy" name="fd[noy]" onchange="noy(document.Form, this.value);"><option value=""></option>
<option value="12months">12months</option>
<option value="24months">24months</option>
<option value="36months">36months</option>
<option value="48months">48months</option>
<option value="60months">60months</option></select>

    <label for="fd_Rate_of_interest">Rate of interest</label><span class="help-block">auto-generated</span>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="roi" name="fd[roi]" size="30" type="text">

Comment: @Sandeeproop <label for="fd_Period">Period</label>
<select id="fd_noy" name="fd[noy]" onchange="noy(document.Form, this.value);"><option value=""></option>
<option value="12months">12months</option>
<option value="24months">24months</option>
<option value="36months">36months</option>
<option value="48months">48months</option>
<option value="60months">60months</option></select>

<label for="fd_Rate_of_interest">Rate of interest</label><span class="help-block">auto-generated</span>
<input disabled="disabled" id="roi" name="fd[roi]" size="30" type="text">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your JavaScript

```
form.elements.noy.onchange
```

to

```
form.elements.fd_noy.onchange
```

and var roivalues as suggested by @Sandeeproop

This is solution.

```
var roivalues = {

  '12months': 9.5,
  '24months': 10,
  '36months': 10.5,
  '48months': 11,
  '60months': 11.5
};

var form = document.getElementById('roidetails');

form.elements.fd_noy.onchange = function ()

 {
    var form = this.form;

    form.elements.roi.value = roivalues[this.value];

};
```

Comment: Boss, I have changed as you and Sandeep suggest, this too not working boss.

Comment: (tail -f log/development.log)
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 10:24:33 +0530
Served asset /bootstrap-popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/fds.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 10:24:33 +0530
Served asset /fds.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/money.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 10:24:33 +0530
Served asset /money.jpg - 304 Not Modified (4ms)

Comment: I think this is the command to see console logs "tail -f log/development.log"  Right?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
var roivalues = {

   '12 Months': 9.5,
   '24 Months': 10,
   '36 Months': 10.5,
   '48 Months': 11,
   '60 Months': 11.5
};
```

with this

```
var roivalues = {

  '12months': 9.5,
  '24months': 10,
  '36months': 10.5,
  '48months': 11,
  '60months': 11.5
};
```

Comment: Can you try after removing this line from your code "var form = this.form;"

Comment: Yes, i have removed it. Still the same result... Plz, Help me.

Comment: Can you check your browser console for any errors. If you are using FF check firebug console.

Comment: I'm using firefox 11.0 for that firebug is not supporting

Comment: I gave inspect element it shows:   <label for="fd_Period">Period</label>
    <select id="fd_noy" name="fd[noy]" onchange="noy(document.Form, this.value);"><option value=""></option>
<option value="12months">12months</option>
<option value="24months">24months</option>
<option value="36months">36months</option>
<option value="48months">48months</option>
<option value="60months">60months</option></select>

    <label for="fd_Rate_of_interest">Rate of interest</label><span class="help-block">auto-generated</span>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="roi" name="fd[roi]" size="30" type="text" />

Comment: in chrome console it shows some error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of null fds:82
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught ReferenceError: noy is not defined fds:282

Comment: Can you show me the body of function noy() from <select id="fd_noy" name="fd[noy]" onchange="noy(document.Form, this.value);">

Comment: Also please upgrade your firefox currently it is on 29 version and you are using 11, which is way old.

Comment: this is the body function: <select id="fd_noy" onchange="noy(document.Form, this.value);" name="fd[noy]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="12months">12months</option>
<option value="24months">24months</option>
<option value="36months">36months</option>
<option value="48months">48months</option>
<option value="60months">60months</option>
</select>
<label for="fd_Rate_of_interest">Rate of interest</label

Comment: :Also i have updated my FF 11.0 to 30 and added firebug.

Comment: No I am asking about noy "function" body. means function noy(){//some code here}

Comment: Sorry boss, i'm not having any function for noy. How to proceed further?. I'm very new to javascript and don't know how to use it  for rails... :(

Answer (score 0):

The above javascript is not working for me so i go with the following site and this is working perfectly for my requirements.   Thank you Mr. Sandeeproop and Sanket for your support.                                                  http://www.codingforums.com/general-web-building/178397-change-text-box-value-based-drop-down-value-selected.html